# Array to List Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an array to list(containing objects) and first object is connected to next pair value.

This is what I have done so far:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3] ;
function arrayToList()
{
    var myList = Object.keys(myArray).map(function(key){

        return { value: myArray[key],rest:myArray[key]}    

    });
    console.log(myList);
}
arrayToList(myArray);
```

This should return Like this:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

, when given an array of [1,2,3]

Comment: instead of rest being `rest:myArray[key]`, call `arrayToList()` again - but give an offset so you will eventually stop recursing.

Comment: `Object.keys(myArray)` makes no sense since you have an array, not an object.

Comment: What would you want the output to be when the array is empty? Should it just return `null`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight)

```js
function arrayToList(arr) {
  return arr.reduceRight((rest, value) => ({ value, rest }), null);
}

console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: It is working but when you expand the 2nd value in browser it disappears and all you can see it value 1 and value 3. One more thing if you want to do the reverse for List to Array what one can do ? The output for the first one is {value: 1, rest: {…}}rest: rest: rest: nullvalue: 3__proto__: Objectvalue: 2__proto__: Objectvalue: 1__proto__: Object

Comment: @NaumanMughal The value doesn't disappear. The browser displays it below the expanded object. If you want, you could do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayToList([1, 2, 3])));` for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This lends itself well to a simple 1-line recursive function (especially nice with es6):

```js
function tolist([value, ...rest]) {
      return {value, rest: rest.length ? tolist(rest): null}
}

console.log(tolist([0, 2, 3, 4]))
```